# How to prevent Android from thinking some numbers are phone numbers?

Tags: android, html

I have a website with an html calendar (table) like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        ...
    </tr>
    ...
    <tr>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>24</td>
        <td>25</td>
        <td>26</td>
        ...
    </tr>
</table>
```

When you click on say the cell with the 23 in it, the phone's dialer comes up asking to dial 232-242-526 (which isn't even a real number, at least in my country)

Not all versions do this (particularly newer ones) but I know 2.3 does it for sure.

I've tried throwing in spans with `display:none;` and random characters to trick it, but that didn't work. How can I keep it from thinking that's a phone number? I'd think the html markup would be enough.

Comment: Have you tried: <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">?

Comment: @zvona I had not. That did the trick, thanks.